# How to query the number of rows in Laravel 5.2 using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am looking to query the number of rows as part of an if statement.

The code I have used is below:

```
 $company = DB::table('customers')->where('business', 'Auth::user()->name')->value('business');   
@if (count($company==0)

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<strong>Please click here to register full company details</strong>

@endif
```

**UPDATE**

```
{{$countCompany = App\customers::where('business', Auth::user()->name)->count()}}
@if ($countCompany==0)
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<strong>Please click here to register full company details</strong>
@endif
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do a workaround

```
<?php
$user = Auth::user()->name;
$company = DB::table('customers')->where('business', $user )->value('business');

?>

@if (is_null($company))

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<strong>Please click here to register full company details</strong>
</div>
@endif
```

Works for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `->count()` method

```
$count = $company->count();
```

Also you have error here, missing `)`

```
@if (count($company==0))
```

Comment: Thanks @Rishi I have updated to use your technique I am however getting "Call to a member function count() on a non-object"

I am trying to do this in a messages partial within blade if that helps.

Comment: `@if (count($company==0))` should of course be `@if (count($company)==0)` or better `@if (!count($company))`

Answer (score 0):

try it with Eloquent

```
$countCompany = App\Customer::where('business', Auth::user()->name)->count();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Abderrahim Soubai Elidrissi, I have updated the code above. I am getting a reply of "trying to get property of a non-object" I am trying to do this in a messages partial within blade if that helps.

Comment: Welcome Bro , be sure that Customer is the name of Model to your Customers table. and try to dispatche query from display so query in you Controller and pass the data to your view by using ->With()